# Помогите со скриптом в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию мышкой (тапом) несколько раз, персонаж ускорялся. Например, на денди была игра Hyper Sports (Прыжки в длину, бег на 100 м и тд).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого нужно отслеживать кол-во кликов мыши или тапов. В случае необходимости нажатий/тапов именно подряд, то обнуляем счетчик нажатий при отсутствии тапов/нажатий какое-то время.

При каждом нажатии/тапе проверяем значение счетчика. Если он равен необходимому количеству для активации ускорения, то обнуляем счетчик и придаем ускорение персонажу - увеличиваем его скорость.

Вопрос достаточно общий, потому и ответ получается тоже довольно-таки общим... Будет код - будет конкретика.

**UPD**

Если скорость должна увеличиваться при КАЖДОМ нажатии, то какую-нибудь проверку максимальной скорости стоит делать только в том случае, если есть ограничение максимальной скорости. Если ограничения нет, то вполне достаточно отдельно хранить "базовую" скорость.
Я бы сделал примерно так:

```
public class PlayerController
{
//для данной немного абстрактной ситуации для удобства редактирования коэффициентов все переменные общедоступные. в финальной версии лучше все "лишнее" объявить с модификатором private
public float speedDefault = 10.0f;      //Базовая скорость
public float boostAtTab = 0.5f;         //Ускорение за 1 нажатие
public float slowAtSecond = 5.0f;       //Замедление в секунду

public float speedCurrent;              //Текущая скорость

public bool isInit = false;

private void Update()
{
    if (isInit)
    {
        //Здесь код перемещения за кадр, где должна учитываться текущая скорость speedCurrent;
        //...
    }
}

//Инициализация, в конкретном случае должна быть вызвана вручную каким-либо образом
public void Initialize()
{
    isInit = true;
    speedCurrent = speedDefault;
    StartCoroutine(SpeedControl());
}

//Придаем ускорение. Нужно вызывать этот медод при каждом нажатии/тапе
public void OnBoost()
{
    speedCurrent += boostAtTab;
}

//Сопрограмма контроля скорости - постоянно снижает, но не ниже скорости "по умолчанию"
private IEnumerator SpeedControl()
{
    while (isInit)
    {
        if (speedCurrent > speedDefault)
        {
            speedCurrent -= slowAtSecond * Time.deltaTime;

            if (speedCurrent < speedDefault)
                speedCurrent = speedDefault;
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Я новичок, как Вы уже поняли. 
1) Мне создать макс.скорость float, и отдельно текущую скорость и прибавлять по сколько то единиц, когда Тапаю пока не будет равно макс скорости? Или Только текущую скорость, которая if > 10.0f (к примеру) вернуть текущую скорость? 
2) Каждый тап должен добавлять ускорение.
3) OnMouseDown() использовать?

Comment: @PinPin

1. Какие данные запоминать - зависит от того, есть ли максимальная скорость и какие конкретные правила придания ускорения Игроку

2. По Вашему комментарию ответил на пп.1 и 2 в основном ответе выше

3.  OnMouseDown() работает только с GUI и коллайдерами. Если принцип ввода в игре такой, то можно использовать и его. Раз Вы говорите, что "новичек", то для начала было бы достаточно разместить кнопку Button и в событии OnClick в окне Инспектора задать метод OnBoost из примера выше

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас всё посмотрю,  разберусь. Благодарю.